# Showing an empty column on table with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a new column on a table via JavaScript.

Now, I want to show the empty column at its adding index position where this addition takes place. Also it must be hide when addition of column is done at its index position.

method code:

```
function addColumn(tblId, colIndexVal)
  {

//New Header 

    var tblHeadObj = document.getElementById(tblId).tHead;

for (var h=0; h<tblHeadObj.rows.length; h++) {
      var newTH = document.createElement('th');

   tblHeadObj.rows[h].insertBefore(newTH, tblHeadObj.rows[h].children[colIndexVal] );

       newTH.innerHTML = "New Col Header";
    }

//New Column cells

    var tblBodyObj = document.getElementById(tblId).tBodies[0];
    for (var i=0; i<tblBodyObj.rows.length; i++) {
      var newCell = tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(colIndexVal);
      newCell.innerHTML = 'new cells'
  )
    }


  }
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this. 
Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, and where you are struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my plain-JavaScript *best-guess* at what I *think* you want, given the lack of clarity in, or my understanding of, your question. It also features a couple of simple (non-sanity-checked) methods to allow easier traversal/retrieval (again: no sanity-checks, so be careful with, or improve, them):

```
/* trying to reduce the necessity of
   'this.parentNode.parentNode' etc, to
   remove the need to know the exact structure */
Object.prototype.closest = function (elType) {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    return parent.tagName.toLowerCase() == elType.toLowerCase() ? parent : parent.closest(elType);
};

/* a simple non-sanity-checked means to find,
   and filter, the sibling elements of a node */
Object.prototype.siblings = function (filter) {
    var parent = this.parentNode,
        s = parent.children,
        rs = [],
        c, t;
    for (var i = 0, len = s.length; i < len; i++) {
        c = s[i].className;
        t = s[i].tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (c.indexOf(filter) > -1 || t == filter) {
            rs.push(s[i]);
        }
    }
    return filter ? rs : s;
}

// no attempt whatsoever is being made to make this IE compatible
var table = document.querySelector('table');

function addColumn(e) {
    var self = e.target,
        cell = self.parentNode,
        rows = self.closest('tr').siblings('tr'),
        index = cell.cellIndex,
        newEl;
    for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
        rows[i].insertCell(index + 1);
        newEl = rows[i].children[index + 1];
        // uncomment below if you want to hide:
        // newEl.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

table.addEventListener('click', addColumn, false);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bvhN4/1/).

Answer (score 0):

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9acN/1/)

You can add a new column on a table by inserting a `td` element in each row.

```
function addCol()
{
    $("table thead tr").each(function() {
        var td = $("<th>");
        var index = $(this).find("th").length;
        td.html("Col index " + index);
        td.appendTo(this);
    });

    $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
        var td = $("<td>");
        td.appendTo(this);
    });
}

addCol();
addCol();
```

Comment: How can we get it by javascript.. also want show/hide form of this column as its adding index gets change dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to use eq to get the index and then insert the new row (and possibly header) before the newly created index.

Something like this:

```
var table = $("table") // select your table,
    index = 3, // index where to insert
    newRow = $("<td></td>");
table.find("th").eq(index).before(newRow)
```

Full Example (adding header values as well):
http://jsfiddle.net/cTNqX/